# The warning : Could not find UsbSerialLibrary.apk

Tags: android, android-intent, usbserial

I am working on the USB serial. I want to make a Nexus to read data from USB.

I found the example project to do it. [here](http://code.google.com/p/usb-serial-for-android/source/browse/#git/UsbSerialExamples%253Fstate%253Dclosed)

So, I cloned the project and complied with eclipse. 
Everything works well but I got this warning, and I tried to connect my usb to the Nexus by serial port. However, it cannot find my usb. I don't know maybe it's because the warning.

I searched and found some recommendations but they don't work for me.

Furthermore, I have add my usb's product-id and vendor-id to a xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <usb-device vendor-id="1516" product-id="8628" />
</resources>
```

Could you help me find it out?

[image]

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using the UsbSerialLibrary as a Library for your main project?
In that case please go to:

```
Main project's properties -> build path -> projects tab
```

and make sure to remove the UsbSerialLibrary from that place. You should make sure it is present in

```
Main project's properties -> android -> Library
```

If it is not there, please select add and that should be it.
Hope this helps to remove that warning.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @unbekant, It works well !!. Have you ever worked on this project? Can I ask you some questions? My app can be installed as well. But it always show "No serial device". It cannot find my USB. I don't know why. :(

Comment: Now, I found that the number of a vendor_id and a product_id should be in hex. I can found my USB. However, I keep forward to make it able to read data.

Comment: @Willy Glad that made it! Unfortunately I haven't worked with that project but that warning is very common in any project using libraries. Good luck! :)

Comment: don't worry. Thank you for your help ! I appreciate.